# Does OpenSSL 1.0.1h also suffer from POODLE attack like SSL 3.0 suffers?

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, vpn, openvpn

*SSL 3.0* library suffers from **POODLE** attack.

*OpenSSL's* latest version is *1.0.1h* as of now.

Does *OpenSSL* also suffer from the same attack ?

I couldn't find any related info either on google or OpenSSL forum.

I use a *openvpn android client* which uses *OpenSSL 1.0.1 h* that is why I am worried.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes **OpenSSL 1.0.1h** suffers from the **POODLE** attack.

But you don't have to worry as **OpenVPN** has always been strictly **TLS 1.0** or **TLS 1.0+**  and since **OpenVPN 2.x** never supported **SSLv3** or **SSLv3** fallback as well.

Here is a link for your [reference](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Poodle)

Hope this helps

Comment: FYI: http://duraiamuthan.blogspot.in/2015/02/how-to-protect-yourself-agains-poodle.html